# If-statement when starting

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I am currently developing an app, which upon clearing data and/or installing must let the user enter data. So far I have achieved none of it, since every time I run it in emulator, it comes with the `EditTexts` hidden and rest showing. I have tried an `if-statement` but I am not sure if it is correct.
Code is as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    checkFirstRun();
    savedData();

    }

public void savedData() {
    showGoalTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    showBeamsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    showGoalEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    checkBtnPressed = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    showBeamsEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    beamsGoal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

    //Fetch the stored data and display it upon starting.
    String goalSave = showGoalTextView.getText().toString();
    String beamsSave = showBeamsTextView.getText().toString();


    preferences = getSharedPreferences("userData", MODE_PRIVATE);

    goalSave = preferences.getString("goals", goalSave);
    if (goalSave != null) {
        showGoalTextView.setText(goalSave);
        hideAll();
    } else {
        resetAll();
    }

    beamsSave = preferences.getString("beam", beamsSave);
    if (beamsSave != "0") {
        showBeamsTextView.setText(beamsSave);
        hideAll();
    } else {
        resetAll();
    }
}


public void checkFirstRun() {
    final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    final String PREF_VERSION_CODE_KEY = "version_code";
    final int DOESNT_EXIST = -1;

    //Get current version code
    int currentVersionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;

    //Get saved version
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    int savedVersionCode = preferences.getInt(PREF_VERSION_CODE_KEY, DOESNT_EXIST);

    //Check for first run or upgrade
    if (currentVersionCode == savedVersionCode) {
        //No big deal
        return;
    } else if (savedVersionCode == DOESNT_EXIST) {
        //TODO This is a new install

    } else if (currentVersionCode > savedVersionCode) {
        //TODO This is an upgrade
        return;
    }

    //Update sharedPreferences with the current version code
    preferences.edit().putInt(PREF_VERSION_CODE_KEY, currentVersionCode).apply();
}

public void hideAll() {
    TextView showGoalTextView =
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    EditText showGoalEditText =
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ImageButton checkBtnPressed =
            (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    EditText showBeamsEditText =
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    EditText beamsGoal =
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

    //Hide rest
    showGoalEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    checkBtnPressed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    showBeamsEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    beamsGoal.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
public void resetAll() {
    //For when resetting
    TextView showGoalTextView =
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    EditText showGoalEditText =
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ImageButton checkBtnPressed =
            (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    EditText showBeamsEditText =
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    EditText beamsGoal =
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

    //Clear editTexts
    showGoalEditText.getText().clear();
    showBeamsEditText.getText().clear();

    //Show all editTexts
    showGoalEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    checkBtnPressed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    showBeamsEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    beamsGoal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    //Get the text view
    TextView showResetTextView =
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    //Get the value of the text view
    String resetString = showResetTextView.getText().toString();

    //Convert value to a number and reset it
    Integer reset = Integer.parseInt(resetString);
    reset = 0;

    //Display the new value in the text view.
    showResetTextView.setText(reset.toString());
    showGoalTextView.setText("BEAMS");
}
```

Can anyone help me out with the correct `if-statement`? I want it to show the user data to enter, when sharedPreferences are empty (which they will, if user installs app and/or clears data.

This block:

```
    preferences = getSharedPreferences("userData", MODE_PRIVATE);

    goalSave = preferences.getString("goals", goalSave);
    if (goalSave != null) {
        showGoalTextView.setText(goalSave);
        hideAll();
    } else {
        resetAll();
    }

    beamsSave = preferences.getString("beam", beamsSave);
    if (beamsSave != "0") {
        showBeamsTextView.setText(beamsSave);
        hideAll();
    } else {
        resetAll();
    }
```

If you would like to know what I exactly mean, please download my beta app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jhpcoenen.connectlife.beams

Thank you in advance!

Comment: which if ststement are you exactly talking about ??

Comment: Please review the question again, I have updated it to specify the block of code that I am struggling with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is you are using the same edittext id for both of the edit text so use appropriate ID

```
EditText showBeamsEditText =
        (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
EditText beamsGoal =
        (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
```

`showBeamsEditText` and `beamsGoal` should have different ids instead of `editText4` for both

and change `beamsSave != "0"` to `beamsSave.equals("0")`, [How to compare strings in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out! Completely read over it. However, `showBeamsEditText` and `beamsGoal` were the exact same thing, so I have deleted it.

Comment: Please review the question again, I have clarified which `if-statement` I am currently struggling with. Hope you can help me with it.

Comment: @JamieCoenen and change  `beamsSave != "0"` to `beamsSave.equals("0")`

Comment: My apologies, I have now *correctly* implemented your suggestion and now it works!

Comment: @JamieCoenen then it's mean the value is different so simply use log or toast to see the value of `goalSave` and then apply `if` condition, for empty string, use `if (!goalSave.isEmpty())`

Comment: i am glad that i could help, happy coding

Answer (score 1):

`GoalSave` will never be `null` so just remove the null checking..and replace with `.isEmpty()` check instead

Comment: Thank you very much! Your suggestions worked like a charm, upon install it gives the correct screen. Also clearing the data and then running, makes it give the correct screen!